# How to update a GitHub access token via command line

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, access-token

I use the git integration with VSCode and got the notification today that I need to renew my access token. I did so and have my new token (which I obtained through the web interface). Now I need to set my local git configuration to use the new token instead of the old one which will expire in a few days.

The [VSCode docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KnisterPeter.vscode-github#:%7E:text=Setup%20Personal%20Access%20Token&text=To%20execute%20the%20%27GitHub%3A%20Set,the%20token%20generated%20from%20GitHub.) suggest the following:

> To execute the 'GitHub: Set Personal Access Token' type Ctrl+Shift+p in VSCode to open the command palette and type 'GitHub: Set Personal Access Token'. You will then be prompted to enter the token generated from GitHub.

This option isn't available in my git integration in VS code (maybe I need an update?)

How can I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, first clear the existing credentials using the Credential Manager. For non-windows systems, [remove your git credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) however appropriate. The next time you perform a Git operation, you will be prompted for a username and password. Enter the new token as your password. This solution avoids the problem of exposing your token in plain text.

On Windows, to open Credential Manager, type "credential manager" in the search box on the taskbar and select Credential Manager Control panel. Then select the "Windows Credentials" button, find Git, and click "remove".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 37):

If you want to update Github Personal Access Token in VSCode, you need to install [Github Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KnisterPeter.vscode-github)

You can also update Github Personal Access Token via command line

1. Open a command line and set the current directory to your project root
2. Run the command to set remote access via a token

   `git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git`

Example:

```
git remote set-url origin https://exampleuser:b8c28127***63gu56b2d@github.com/exampleuser/exampleproject.git
```

Comment: If the token begins with 'ghp_' for example 'ghp_f0ir...sjx' enter it completely, including this 'ghp_' text.

Comment: Putting the access token in the remote url will write your access token in the file .git/config of your git repository, in clear text, which is a bad practice and raise a number of security issues. You should consider a git credential manager instead...

Comment: @tk_ for me that case did not work. it says `no such remote 'origin'`

Comment: Just a side note, `/exampleuser/exampleproject.git` here `exampleuser` could also be `exampleorganization` depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are running on windows, but modern git binaries are using windows credential manager to store the GitHub / Git authentication details. To modify them, go to the windows "credential manager". The procedure is detailed here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/changing-git-credentials-in-windows